# react native value from picker

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, picker

doc : https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker

constructor :

```
constructor(props) {        
  super(props);         
  this.state = {            
      showPass: true,
      press: false,
      email: "",
      age: 0,
      sexe:"",
      password: "",
      confirmPass: ""       
     } 
  }
```

JSX :

```
<Picker
    selectedValue={this.state.sexe}
    onValueChange={(value) => {this.setState({sexe: value})}}>
    <Picker.Item label="Homme" value="homme" />
    <Picker.Item label="Femme" value="femme" />
</Picker>
```

Problem : i don't know why this.state.sexe isn't affected

[image: Database user]
PS : beginner in react native

Comment: is this problem on iOS?

Comment: Android, But I think it's my code that's bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify default selection on state ,then only the onValueChange going to trigger

try below code

```
  constructor(props) {        
  super(props);         
  this.state = {            
      showPass: true,
      press: false,
      email: "",
      age: 0,
      sexe:"homme",
      password: "",
      confirmPass: ""       
     } 
  }
```

and JSX

```
<Picker
    selectedValue={this.state.sexe}
    onValueChange={(value) => {this.setState({sexe: value})}}>
    <Picker.Item label="Homme" value="homme" />
    <Picker.Item label="Femme" value="femme" />
</Picker>
```